# How to get string from url in ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I think my tittle is inaccurate.

When a user clicks on a button I need it to do this:

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?userid=XX");
```

How can I get the `"userid?"` from `?userid.` so I can show a page. Like doing `"?page=3"` and show `page 3`, in the same page or something.

The Button code is: (just if you need it)

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Thanks a lot! Sorry if I didn't ask it good, and sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use Request.QueryString:

First Page Sends them another page with their user id in the url:

```
Response.Redirect("AfterLogIn.aspx?userid=23");
```

You then Read it using the below code:

```
var g = Request.QueryString["userid"] //this value should be 23 now
```

You could then use this g variable to do any amount of custom things (Hide panels, show controls, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var id = // whatever userid
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?userid="+ id);
        }
```

and in the `pageload` of Login page

```
    var userid = Request.QueryString["userid"];
```

[ASP.NET State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) will explain further.

Hope this helps